# Coffeescript variable concatenation causes "Uncaught TypeError value is not a function"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm creating an app in Rails that uses ActionCable/Websockets and I'm using coffeescript to update a users browser with data received from the current channel in ActionCable. When I run this code I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: data.user.name is not a function", however when I swap data.user.id and data.user.name the error is then for data.user.id. I think my syntax is wrong but I can't find any answers. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
received: (data) ->
  $('#players-table').show()
  $('#players-table-body').append '<tr>' + 
    '<td>' + data.user.id + '</td>' + 
    '<td>' + data.user.name +'</td>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll sound strange, but you need an space after the last `+`:

```
received: (data) ->
  $('#players-table').show()
  $('#players-table-body').append '<tr>' + 
    '<td>' + data.user.id + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + data.user.name + '</td>'
```

Without it, it'd make the `data.user.name` to open parenthesis and to put inside the `+'</td>'`, like:

```
return $('#players-table-body').append('<tr>' + '<td>' + data.user.id + '</td>' + '<td>' + data.user.name(+'</td>'));
```

Comment: Great it worked, I've just edited the title if somebody else has the same problem.

Comment: yeah thanks, I did mark it but said I had to wait 10 mins